# Running logstash with monit

Tags: ubuntu, monit

I am trying to start logstash with monit. 
I have a directory where i have logstash in which /home/slee/PROJECT/logstash.

First I create a bash script(wrapper) to run logstash in as suggested in the monit site. 
I created this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/
#CLASSPATH=/root/lo2/logstash/logstash-1.1.0-monolithic.jar
#CONFIG=/root/lo2/logstash/stag_conf.conf
CLASSPATH=/home/slee/PROJECT/logstash/logstash-1.1.0-monolithic.jar
CONFIG=/home/slee/PROJECT/logstash/local.conf

case $1 in
start)
    echo $$ > /var/run/logstash.pid;
    #exec 2>&1 java -jar $CLASSPATH agent -f $CONFIG -- web --backend elasticsearch:///?local 1> /var/log/apache2/logstash.log
    exec java -jar $CLASSPATH agent -f $CONFIG --log /var/log/logstash-indexer.out -- web --log /var/log/logstash-web.out --backend elasticsearch://localhost/
    ;;
stop)
    kill `cat /var/run/logstash.pid` ;;
*)
echo "usage: logstash {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

If I run this with ./logstash start. It works like a charm but if I add it to monit as such:

```
check process logstash with pidfile /var/run/logstash.pid
group system
start program = "/bin/bash /home/slee/PROJECT/twyxt/logstash/logstash.sh"
stop  program = "/bin/bash /home/slee/PROJECT/twyxt/logstash/logstash.sh"
if failed host localhost port 9292
protocol http then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

It does not start logstash at all. Can anyone tell me why? Or give me an Idea on how to solve this.

I sent an email to the logstash group and they gave me this link http://cookbook.logstash.net/recipes/using-upstart/#upstart%20logstash%20config

I tried it but I kept getting a 
    slee@ubuntu:~/PROJECT/logstash/upstart/backup$ sudo initctl start logstash
    initctl: Unknown job: logstash

I dont know what could be wrong with the logstash config since I changed the directory to my own. Please help.

Best Regards,
Stevenson Lee

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the only way to get monit to start java processes is to use the `Java Service Wrapper`.  I've seen examples that show monit starting java directly but they just won't work for me.

ElasticSearch describes the [Java Service Wrapper](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-458

I added a HOME variable to my startup script and now it starts up through monit